Interchange limit and supremum of functionals over a convex set
Let $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $B\subset H$ be (nonempty and) convex, and suppose that $(\alpha_k)\subset H$ is a sequence for which the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle$ exists (in $\mathbb{R}$) for each $q\in B$.
Under which additional assumptions do we have that
$$\tag{1}
\inf_{q\in B}\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle \,=\, \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{q\in B}\,\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle \,?
$$
Note that we cannot assume the sequence of functions $\langle\alpha_k, \cdot\rangle$ to converge uniformly on $B$.

If $B$ is bounded and closed (or alternatively if $B$ is just bounded but $(\alpha_k)$ is uniformly bounded), then you can use weak compactness to find, for each $k$, a nonempty compact face $B_k \subset \bar{B}$ which minimizes $\langle \alpha_k, \cdot \rangle$. If $B_k$ (or some tail of it) satisfies the finite intersection property, then again by weak compactness you have a global minimized for all $k$, from which it is easy to show the equality you want. (But this is a relatively strong condition to require. Not sure if it’s useful for your purposes.)

Thanks for your comment, @DavidGao! Your conditions are indeed a bit stronger than what I hoped for, especially the required finite intersection property. However, if you want to elaborate your comment into a full answer, I'm happy to accept it.

As requested, here is an elaboration of my comment, promoted to an answer:
Assuming $B$ is bounded and closed. Since $B$ is convex, by Hahn-Banach, it is also weakly closed and therefore weakly compact. For each $k$, $\langle \alpha_k, \cdot \rangle$ is (weakly) continuous and therefore the set of minimizers $B_k = \{x \in B: \langle \alpha_k, x \rangle = \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \}$ is nonempty. It is also easy to see that $B_k$ must be a (weakly) closed face of $B$. Now, if some tail of $B_k$ satisfies the finite intersection property, that is, there exists $K > 0$ s.t. whenever $k_1, \cdots, k_n \geq K$, we have $\cap_{i=1}^n B_{k_i} \neq \varnothing$, then $\cap_{k \geq K} B_k \neq \varnothing$ by the weak compactness of $B$. But this means we may choose $x \in \cap_{k \geq K} B_k$ and we would have $\langle \alpha_k, x \rangle = \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$ for all $k \geq K$. Thus,
$$\inf_{q \in B} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, x \rangle = \lim_{k \to \infty} \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$$
For any fixed $q_0 \in B$, we also have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle$, so $\lim_{k \to \infty} \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \leq \inf_{q \in B} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$. Thus, we have the desired equality in this case.
Now, if $B$ is only assumed bounded but $(\alpha_k)_k$ is also assumed uniformly bounded, then a similar result holds as well. This is because we can rewrite the infima to range over $\bar{B}$, which would be closed, bounded, and convex. We first show that $\langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle$ converges for all $q_0 \in \bar{B}$. Let $C > 0$ be such that $\|\alpha_k\| \leq C$ for all $k$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $q_1 \in B$ with $\|q_0 - q_1\| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{C}$, and we have,
$$\begin{split}
\limsup_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle &\leq \limsup_{k \to \infty} (\langle \alpha_k, q_1 \rangle + \|\alpha_k\|\|q_0 - q_1\|)\\
&\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_1 \rangle + \epsilon\\
&\leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} (\langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle + \|\alpha_k\|\|q_0 - q_1\|) + \epsilon\\
&\leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle + 2\epsilon
\end{split}$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we get $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle$, i.e., $\langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle$ converges. Now, again, for any $q_0 \in \bar{B}$, choose $q_1 \in B$ with $\|q_0 - q_1\| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{C}$, and we have,
$$\begin{split}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_0 \rangle &\geq \limsup_{k \to \infty} (\langle \alpha_k, q_1 \rangle - \|\alpha_k\|\|q_0 - q_1\|)\\
&\geq \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q_1 \rangle - \epsilon\\
&\geq \inf_{q \in B} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle - \epsilon
\end{split}$$
Since $q_0 \in \bar{B}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ are arbitrary, we have,
$$\inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \geq \inf_{q \in B} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle $$
The inequality in the other direction is obvious, so,
$$\inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle = \inf_{q \in B} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$$
It is obvious that for each fixed $k$, we have $\inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle = \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$, so the required equality is equivalent to,
$$\inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle = \lim_{k \to \infty} \inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle$$
Now set $B_k = \{x \in \bar{B}: \langle \alpha_k, x \rangle = \inf_{q \in \bar{B}} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \}$. If some tails of $B_k$ satisfies the finite intersection property, then by the previous result we get the required equality.
